# Insert in an array elements that fulfill condition

Tags: javascript

**Context**

```
class Park extends Place {
    constructor(name, build_year, number_trees, area, tree_density){
        super(name, build_year);
        this.number_tress = number_trees;
        this.area = area;
        this.tree_density = number_trees/area;
    } `

`const park1 = new Park("Jadim botanico", 1958, 30, 30);
 const park2 = new Park("Tangua", 1990, 60, 15);
 const park3 = new Park("Bosque do Papa", 1996, 10000, 300);
 arr_park = [park1, park2, park3];`
```

**Goal**

Retrieve all the parks that have more than 1000 trees.

**Solution**

```
var bushyPark = arr_park.map(cur => {if(cur.number_tress>1000){return cur.name}}).filter(cur => cur);
```

**Question**

Is it possible to do the same thing using ternary operator without filter?

```
var bushyPark = arr_park.map(cur => (cur.number_tress > 1000) ? cur : ??
```

Comment: why do you not want to use `filter` ?

Comment: What is wrong with `var bushyPark = arr_park.filter(p => p.number_trees > 1000);`? Edit: never mind, the existing answer did not load in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use `.filter` without `.map` method, it is unnecessary in this case:

```
const bushyPark = arr_park.filter(cur => cur.number_tress>1000);
console.log('new array: ', bushyPark);
```

`.map`: this method is used to manipulate/change the content of every item in the array.

`.filter`: this method is used to return only the array items that satisfy a boolean criteria.

**Here is a definition for the `.filter` method for a better understanding:**

The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function). Note: filter() does not execute the function for array elements without values. Note: filter() does not change the original array.

Another solution using only `.map`:

```
let newNamesArray = [];
arr_park.map(cur => {
  if(cur.number_tress>1000){
   newNamesArray.push(cur.name);
  }
  return cur;
})
console.log('newNamesArray: ', newNamesArray);
```

Comment: Almost there, could you please explain how to make an array of the names of the parks? In your case I am getting an array of park objects.

Comment: @eggrobot78 you can use this: `arr_park.filter(cur => cur.number_tress>1000).map(item => item.name)` so basically you use map after your filter method.

Comment: How about ternary operator, is there a way to skip condition if doesn't match?

Comment: why you want to use ternary operator, in your case `.filter` is better suited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.reduce if you want add some conditions like name, try this

```
   arr_park.reduce((acc, ele)=> {
     if(ele.number_tress>1000){
      acc.push(ele.name)
    }
    return acc
    }
    ,[])
```